# django-simple-history how to get the related foreign key objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-simple-history

I have a model named `Order` and another `OrderItem`. The `OrderItem` table has a foreign key to the `Order` table. Now I have the [simple-history][1] installed and setup on both the models. I try to get the Order history and also fetch related OrderItem from history using the related name on the `OrderItem` table but it returns an error:

> AttributeError: 'HistoricalOrder' object has no attribute 'order_items'

Here is my `Order` and `OrderItem` table.

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        "Order", on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="order_items"
    )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    .......

class Order(models.Model):
    po_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    .....
```

Following command gives me an order.

```
 order = Order.history.filter(id=102).first()
```

But if I run `order.order_items.all()` then I get the attribute error.

If I run the query on the actual model then I get the order_items by using below command.

> Order.objects.get(id=102).order_items.all()

Is it possible to get the order_items from the history table in the same way as normal django models. And how can I do this to work.

Thank you.
[1]: https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to try this https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying_history.html#historicforeignkey

HistoricForeignKey would help you to get the related foreign key objects.